# JPA managed entities vs JavaFX properties

Tags: java, jpa, javafx, objectdb

My current project is done using JavaFX. I use properties to bind (bidirectionnal) view fields to bean (with BeanPathAdapter of JFXtras).

I choose to use JPA with ObjectDB as model.

This is the first time I use JPA in a standalone project and here I'm facing the problem of managed entities.

Actually, I bind managed entities to view fields and when the value of a view field changes, the entities is updated... and the database also.

I'm trying to find a way to manually persist/merge an entity so I can ask the user if he wants to save or not.

Here's the code i use to get list :

```
EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("$objectdb/data/db.odb");
EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();

List<XXX> entities = em.createQuery("SELECT x FROM XXX x").getResultList();
```

So when i do

```
entity.setName("test");
```

the entity is updated in the database.

What i'm looking for is that the entity doesn't update automatically.

I tried (just after the getResultList)

```
em.clear();
```

or

```
em.detach(entity);
```

but it looses the relations instances even with CascadeType.DETACH.

I also tried

```
em.setFlushMode(FlushModeType.COMMIT);
```

but it still updates automatically...

I also tried to clone the object. But when i want to merge it, it gives me an exception :

```
Attempt to reuse an existing primary key value
```

I thought an alternative solution : use a variable as 'buffer' and fill the managed bean with buffer if the user saves. But BeanPathAdapter looses its sense. It's the same as filling view fields manually and filling bean fields manually after saving.

Could you help me to find a solution ?

Thanks,

Smoky

**EDIT:**
I answer to my own question :p

After 3 hours of research, I found a solution.

The 'cloning' solution was the 'best' of each I quoted but I don't think it's the best one.

The cause of the exception was the code I used to persist/merge my entity. I was persisting an entity non-managed with an already existing id. I thought I was merging...

I did a generic method not to fail again

```
public <T extends IEntity> T persist(T object) {
    em.getTransaction().begin();

    if (object.getId() == null) {
        em.persist(object);
        em.flush();

        em.getTransaction().commit();

        em.refresh(object);
    }
    else {
        object = em.merge(object);

        em.getTransaction().commit();
    }

    return object;
}
```

So the solution : When I have to bind the entity to the view, I use entity.clone() so I can use the entity as non-managed and merge when I want.

But if you have a proper solution, i'm interested :)

Thanks again

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the solution above, standard solutions are:

- Use detached objects in the model and then merge them into the EntityManager.
- Use managed objects in the model, keeping the EntityManager open (with no detach/merge).